# I want to find the # of subarrays in the array, which has the given sum. But the code doesn't work as I want

Tags: javascript

```
function getSubArrayCount(arr, sum) {

    var count = 0 , n = arr.length, prevSum = new Map(), res = 0,currsum = 0;  

    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {  
        currsum += arr[i];  

        if (currsum == sum)   
            res++;          

        if (prevSum.has(currsum - sum)){

            res += prevSum.get(currsum - sum);  
        }
        count = prevSum.get(currsum);
        if (count === null){

            prevSum.set(currsum, 1); 
        }
        else{

            prevSum.set(currsum, count+1);  
        }}  
  console.log(res);
  return res;
}
getSubArrayCount([1,2,3,2,1,8,-3],5);
getSubArrayCount([1,2,3,4],10);
```

And these conditions should be satisfied

1).The return type should be a string

2).getSubArrayCount([1,2,3,2,1,8,-3],5) should equal to 3

3).getSubArrayCount([1,2,3,4],10) should equal to 1

4).The answer should be valid for any given

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function getSubArrayCount(array, target) {
  var sumCount = 0 , currentSum = 0;
  array.forEach((number, index) => {
  currentSum = array[index];
  for (let i = (index + 1); i < (array.length); i++) {
            currentSum += array[i];
        if (currentSum === target) {
            sumCount++;
        }
    }
  });
  console.log(sumCount);
  return sumCount.toString();
}

alert(getSubArrayCount([2,98,0,100,102,-2,50,50], 100)); // "5"
alert(getSubArrayCount([1,2,3,2,1,8,-3],5)) // "3"
alert(getSubArrayCount([1,2,3,4],10)) // "1"
```

Comment: But the last condition won't satisfied.

Comment: @GaganiSenarathne Edited, should fit the last condition